# Decrypting DES CBC and ECB error: Bad Magic Number

Tags: encryption, openssl

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a BMP file using CBC and ECB with the following commands provided to me:

```
openssl enc -des-cbc -in car.bmp -out car_enc_cbc.bmp -nosalt
openssl enc -des-ecb -in car.bmp -out car_enc_ecb.bmp -nosalt
```

(the password for both is `123`)

When I try to decrypt the files using the commands:

```
openssl enc -des-cbc -d -in car_enc_cbc.bmp -out car_dec_cbc.bmp
openssl enc -des-ecb -d -in car_enc_ecb.bmp -out car_dec_ecb.bmp
```

the console returns the error "bad magic number" for both.

What am I doing wrong? It is important to note that I am attempted to decrypt the files in the same terminal window right after encrypting them. I read that this could be because of mismatched SSL versions, but this case would not apply here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not programming or development. But if you use `enc` to encrypt with PBE and `-nosalt` **you must also decrypt with `-nosalt`**. Also you should know singleDES is not secure at all, and `enc`'s 'normal' PBE EVP_BytesToKey (except in 1.1.1+ with `-pbkdf2` or `-iter` option) is not secure, but those would be offtopic even if this _was_ about programming.

Comment: I completely oversaw the -nosalt. Thank you, you are awesome.

Answer (score 3):

if you use `-nosalt` when encrypt, you need specify parameter `-nosalt` also in decrypt

```
openssl enc -des-cbc -nosalt -d -in car_enc_cbc.bmp -out car_dec_cbc.bmp
openssl enc -des-ecb -nosalt -d -in car_enc_ecb.bmp -out car_dec_ecb.bmp
```